TypeScript function infer generic parameter key from input on another key
I want a function taking an object typed as a generic wherein one key type depends on the type of another key that in turn is a type variable which should be inferred from the input to the function. Example below:
-- Update --
The full inferred type needs to be captured as well, for handling in the function return type. Example revised:
Playground Link
//declare global {
  interface Foo {
    A: {
      hasThing: true
    }
  }
//}
//declare global {  
  interface Foo {
    B: {
      hasThing: false
    }
  }
//}

type Name = keyof Foo

interface Input<$Name extends Name = Name> {
  t: $Name
  u: Foo[$Name] extends true ? (1|2) : (3|4)
}

// CONSTRUCTOR 

const create = <$Input extends Input>(x: $Input): $Input['u'] => { return undefined as any }

// TESTS
// ----------------------------------------------

let x = create({t:'A', u:1})
x = 1 // <- should PASS
// @ts-expect-error
x = 2

// ----------------------------------------------

const y = create({t:'A', u:2})
// @ts-expect-error
x = 1
x = 2 // <- should PASS

// ----------------------------------------------

// @ts-expect-error
create({t:'A', u:3})

// ----------------------------------------------

// @ts-expect-error
create({t:'A', u:4})


-- Original --
interface Input<T extends 'a' | 'b' = 'a' | 'b'> {
  t: T
  u: T extends 'a' ? (1|2) : (3|4)
}

const create = <$Input extends Input>(x: $Input) => x

// create({ t: 'a', u: /* should be 1|2 <- struggling to get this working */ })

create({t:'a',u:1})
create({t:'a',u:2})

// @ts-expect-error
create({t:'a',u:3})

// @ts-expect-error
create({t:'a',u:4})

Playground link

I found a solution via help on TypeScript Discord. I will break down the solution later when I have time. Playground link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAmFMGMBsEMCdwAIDm0D2AjW0kG8AoJJASwDsAXceAM1kmQDF118jikBBALjY44AWsAM4AVAeRS8K8AK7h2xAL7sVINWChxEqDNlx5i7clVr0mLPhwBCvQv2JCxEslKR1owhfxXKC6ggIKAE8AB2QAOVgAW2QAXiQAa3Bg9BokZnRAkPCkAEkyUNkKJAT7DgBtAGlSMiSUtIyWAF07RQcKXir2-lleTOrmioByJ3FJYeakcAAPKjJQYSQZeSQAfiQARiQAHyQAJiReAGZdpAAWdpUlCuTU9MzmwJAkAGEAeQiAZVEAJQBVV6id6-JCBSDoMjCEqQRCwKilJAAHlE0zm4AWSwKRQoAD4ABQzXiiACUxJGskmpVxVmIiAosngdVkC3ANHI4FASBE3LIwQIKn8wCQogAoj8vkKkABaWVy+UKxVK5Uq6WBaDgEozRGw8Dw8D4vCdYacYYAGiQfU2ShJBG1CW2LyR0qQwgE6Fk0C5AAVOF9JS8AAIUYTS2bhSAUMPweDoeB2xH7dWapAzQ4JXX6w3G6zmy3cY42qXB0PhqBR6ix+NpxGXAgarWnDNwqjZ7jDXMWvrnItBkNhmYRisxuN2ptIY7PYWqmezufJkrBHUtg1G9umrvcfa94UlgdD6NVghLh3HxNIJ0ut0er1IX3+qcyufPl9yx97suRw+jzOttcmvM+kLW0pVfMD52LftP2HI9f1XY0N3zHsSSAA.

A playground link does not suffice; please put the plaintext in here or this answer might attract downvotes. I'd do the edit for you, but due to vagaries of copyright laws it's not clear that I have the right to do so, since technically I'd be copying code from another website that I don't have a clear license for (yes, it's encoded in the URL here, no apparently that's not a mitigating factor)

I'm intending to do this but need to find time. It would be incorrect to leave this question as not resolved. Thanks.

You need to find time to copy and paste text? Do you give me permission to do it, assuming you wrote the code at that link?
